Select cells of Array value
I am trying to select the cell location of the array value. My code is not working.
Sub ArrayHeaderSelector()
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        
        ' Header Counter
        LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        ReDim HeaderArray(1 To LastCol)

        ' Header Storage
        For i = 1 To LastCol
            Set HeaderArray(i) = .Cells(1, i)
        Next i

        ' Select cells based on needed columns on array
        .Range(.Cells(1, HeaderArray(2).Column), .Cells(10, HeaderArray(5)).Column).Select

    End With

End Sub

Error Line: "Run-time error '13': Type Mismatch"
        .Range(.Cells(1, HeaderArray(2).Column), .Cells(10, HeaderArray(5)).Column).Select


Maybe .Range(.Cells(1, HeaderArray(2).Column), .Cells(10, HeaderArray(5).Column)).Select? The second .Column in on the wrong bracket.

I suspect you may have over-simplified your actual code. The provided code throws a RTE 1004 for me, not a RTE 13.

Unclear what you want to acheive here, but HeaderArray(2).Column will always be 2 and HeaderArray(5).Column will always be 5
